# Git - pull file only if not already present

Tags: git, updates, pull, ignore

I have a project in my repo and it contains 3 sqlite database files. When I pull the repo on a pc, I need to download those files to in order for the program to work.

But once the files are present locally, I do not want to overwrite them on new pulls. Is there a way to ignore those files only if they already exist? And is there a simple way to force the pull anyway in case of big structural changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `git pull --autostash` might be an option for you.

It stashes the existing changes before pulling applies the stash after pulling, therefore the files are not overwritten by the pull.

For more information see the [git pull options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---autostash)

Note: This does NOT ignore the files while pulling, but the "dirty" files should not be changed by the pull.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow you. If I get it right: --autostash will put all files aside that I have edited locally compared to the last pull, (thus only the databases), and will pull the repo. then it restores all edited files, and if I want to force the update, i can simply delete these files prior to the pull, or pull without the --autostash flag.. Is that correct?

Comment: For the first part, yes it will put the changes aside and restore it to the state before the pull AFTER the pull. For the second part, yes you can than simply pull with `git pull`. However, this may than result in merge conflicts. Before using my answer, i would suggest you to read about [git stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Answer (score 2):

The "right" Git answer here is simply "don't do that".  It's not very satisfying, but it's the only *right* answer.

You can use various tricks to attempt what you're doing, but in the end, none of them will work for every case.  What *will* work for every case is to not have these files in *any* commit.  If a template is required, have a *template* file (in *every* commit), and use some installation process to copy the template file into place.  (That may be as trivial as `make install-databases` or `cp template.sql db.sql` or whatever; you can also set up your software so that when run, if the database isn't there, it's created from the template.)

It's not immediately obvious, but this is in fact a Git [Frequently Asked Question](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F):

> #### How do I tell Git to ignore tracked files?
>
> A common reason to ask this question are configuration files which are added to a project as an example or default, but which individual developers may want to change. Keeping uncommitted changes around is undesirable in the long run ...